# How to improve LINQ to EF performance

Tags: linq, t-sql, entity-framework

I have two classes: Property and PropertyValue. A property has several values where each value is a new revision.

When retrieving a set of properties I want to include the latest revision of the value for each property.

in T-SQL this can very efficiently be done like this:

```
SELECT 
p.Id,
pv1.StringValue,
pv1.Revision
FROM dbo.PropertyValues pv1
LEFT JOIN dbo.PropertyValues pv2 ON pv1.Property_Id = pv2.Property_Id AND pv1.Revision < pv2.Revision
JOIN dbo.Properties p ON p.Id = pv1.Property_Id
WHERE pv2.Id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.Id
```

The "magic" in this query is to join on the lesser than condition and look for rows without a result forced by the LEFT JOIN.

How can I accomplish something similar using LINQ to EF?

The best thing I could come up with was:

```
from pv in context.PropertyValues
group pv by pv.Property into g
select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Revision).FirstOrDefault()
```

It does produce the correct result but is about 10 times slower than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help. Where db is the database context:

```
(
            from pv1 in db.PropertyValues
            from pv2 in db.PropertyValues.Where(a=>a.Property_Id==pv1.Property_Id && pv1.Revision<pv2.Revision).DefaultIfEmpty()
            join p in db.Properties
                on pv1.Property_Id equals p.Id
            where pv2.Id==null
            orderby p.Id
            select new
            {
                p.Id,
                pv1.StringValue,
                pv1.Revision
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Next to optimizing a query in Linq To Entities, you also have to be aware of the work it takes for the Entity Framework to translate your query to SQL and then map the results back to your objects.

Comparing a Linq To Entities query directly to a SQL query will always result in lower performance because the Entity Framework does a lot more work for you.

So it's also important to look at optimizing the steps the Entity Framework takes.

Things that could help:

- Precompile your query
- Pre-generate views
- Decide for yourself when to open the database connection
- Disable tracking (if appropriate)

[Here you can find some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx) with performance strategies.

Comment: Thanks, I compare it using the sql profiler. That should make it as fair as possible when comparing to MMS right?

Comment: If you are looking at the resulting SQL query and measure the execution time of only the SQL part to your handwritten sql it should be fair I think :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use multiple conditions (less than expression) in join you can do this like

```
from pv1 in db.PropertyValues
 join pv2 in db.PropertyValues on new{pv1.Property_ID, Condition = pv1.Revision < pv2.Revision} equals new {pv2.Property_ID , Condition = true} into temp
from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join p in db.Properties
                on pv1.Property_Id equals p.Id
            where t.Id==null
            orderby p.Id
            select new
            {
                p.Id,
                pv1.StringValue,
                pv1.Revision
            }
```

Comment: You are the man! I had no Idea that DefaultOrEmpty() would produce a LEFT JOIN. It's pretty obvious though when you think about it. Had to make a few changes like pv1.Property.Id and where t == null but other than that its spot on! Thanks!

Comment: grouping query is awfully slow cause it executes a separate for each key of the group